# What would explain urine that resists freezing?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, melting-point

A frozen urine specimen is required for an organic acids lab test, but the urine refuses to freeze after 4 days in a regular freezer turned as low as it will go. What would explain this, and how cold might it need to be to freeze?

Comment: Various not-so-legitimate sources say around -120 to -80 degrees celcius. I'd be surprised if there is a simple way to estimate the actual freezing temperature in this case.

Comment: That definitely sounds very far from the mark. A slight bit of time with a search engine afforded [this source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=nCA7AAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA379&ots=s2cr8SJZXn&dq=physics%20freezing%20points%20urine&pg=PA379#v=snippet&q=freezing%20urine&f=false), which states that the freezing point of urine is normally between -1.3 and -2.2°C. I suspect either the freezer is not working properly, or the urine has been significantly preconcentrated, or the urine has been mixed with something else.

Comment: Add a tiny jot of ground glass, a boiling chip, or scratch the side of the container with a glass stir rod.  You need  nucleation centers.

Comment: @UncleAl: unless its sterile filtered there will be a few cells already in there (e.g. exfoliated epithelial cells) so nucleation centers should not be a problem.

Comment: I'd procude a control sample myself and put it in there to see what happens. Of course, tap water does freeze, right?

Answer (score 2):

Urine is an aqueous solution of urea, uric acid, sodium salts and whatnot. These solutions usually exhibit **freezing-point depression**.

As Brian has correctly pointed out in a comment, the effect isn't that strong and a quick and dirty look in the [literature](http://dx.doi.org/10.1159/000285189) shows that a freezing point around -1.3 to -2.2 °C.

You might want to try a cooling bath with dry ice in isopropanol or acetone or other drastic methods to achieve shock-freezing.

Comment: Freezing point depression, as caused by salts such as NaCl, is usually on a much smaller scale. I tried calculating using concentrations from wikipedia, and the freezing point depression came out to around .5 K. Why do we see this 80-120 K freezing point depression?

Comment: some additions can reduce freezing points dramatically.

Comment: According to [another source](https://caspar.green/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-freezing-pee/), freezing point depression based on the urea content is -5.6 °C.